# Python Pandas - Searching two dataframes for matching strings within a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I'm working on a system that performs customized web traffic monitoring in real time. The system (in its current alpha iteration) takes a .txt dump of traffic every few minutes. I'll call it df_webtraffic. This .txt has several columns, one of which is the url field for the web traffic. What I need to do is, for each row's url entry (df_webtraffic.url), scan another df (or series, I don't know how much it matters since it's just one column) of prohibited websites (I'll call it blacklist). The blacklist is large (nearly a million entries), so efficiency is highly important.

I've read dozens of forum posts, but most topics seem related to finding a specific string rather than finding a match within a series. How do I scan a column in one datafield and look for corresponding matches in another datafield or series?

I've written this snippet: `print y[y['URL'].str.contains[(blacklist)]` and it appears to work... but it never completes. It's just processing... and processing... and processing - which I would expect, but system monitor shows that my processor is hardly ever breaking 5% for the python process, never more than 10%, and sits at 0% regularly. For something this demanding I'd expect it to be consuming a lot of CPU.

Thoughts?

Drew

UPDATE:

One thing I wasn't clear on is that a domain in a blacklist isn't always going to be an exact match to a clicked url - someone may click a url that directs to a subdirectory within a domain (like www.website.com/subdir/link.html), however the blacklist entry that I need to correspond this to may only be www.website.com. Thus, I need to see if an entry in the clicked url's contains any entry in the blacklist, even if it doesn't explicitly match it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a hash table for the blacklist. This consists of using some algorithm to convert the urls into a numeric (eg. use the ascii code for each character), then dividing by a large prime number. The larger the prime the fewer the number of clashes. The hash table would contain the resulting number, the string and a pointer for a chain of clashes. You would need a fairly long process to set up the hash table to begin with, but if the number of clashes is low the lookup process should be quick.

More detail on hashing algorithms can be found at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: Thanks for the idea. One thing I don't appear to have been clear on is that a domain in a blacklist isn't going to be an exact match - someone may click a url that directs to a subdirectory within a domain (like www.website.com/subdir/link.html), however the blacklist entry that I need to correspond this to may only be www.website.com. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to replicate your task in a large dataset, I downloaded the [csv file](ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/Presidential_Map/2016/P00000001/P00000001-ALL.zip) of all contributions in the [2016 Presidential Campaign Finance](http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do) to use as an example.

I first import into a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

funding = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv')
```

I then randomly select 10000 contributor zip codes for blacklist

```
zip_list = funding['contbr_zip'].unique()
blacklist = pd.DataFrame(zip_list, columns=['contbr_zip']).sample(n=10000)
```

**The filtering happens here:**

```
selection = funding['contbr_zip'].isin(blacklist['contbr_zip'])
filtered_df = funding[~selection]
```

`filtered_df` now contains only rows where the contributor zip code is not in the blacklist.

Comment: I've played around with .isin. One thing I don't appear to have been clear on is that a domain in a blacklist isn't going to be an exact match - someone may click a url that directs to a subdirectory within a domain (like www.website.com/subdir/link.html), however the blacklist entry that I need to correspond this to may only be www.website.com.

My current code uses str.contains because I need the clicked url to contain any entry from the blacklist - not match it explicitly. Any thoughts in regards to this?

Comment: I would try and reduce the comparisons to an exact match to keep it fast. How about just paring down your URL list to the core domain? Would that be consistent with your logic? Reducing the URL list to some standard form would make the comparisons more streamlined.